# Spring data mongo db custom query problem

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to query an array from Mongo db based on unit key which is like following:

```
unit_details : [
{
"unit_key": "value"
"name" :"name"
"parameters" :[]
},
{
"unit_key": "value"
"name" :"name"
"parameters" :[]
}
]
```

I java this is mapped as a List<Map<String, List>. The problem is I am unable to create a criteria expression to find all the unit_details in a document. All the documents are stored in a char collection. I cannot use @Query because the original database does not have "_class" field which is necessary for using @Query. what other ways can I look at doing this?